# Splitting the image into rows and columns

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a scanned BMP image, which has the candidate number, name and image in a row (number, name and image) these are in column wise.  Now I want to separate each datum of each candidate into separate images using Java.  How to do that?

Here is the ballot paper:

[image: ballot paper]

Comment: You want to extract pictures with 1-16, corresponding names an icons from this big picture, right?

Comment: Will the image be just like shown?  It is easier if there is a scan of the ballot paper that is 1) only the ballot paper 2) 'square' (row/column lines are all vertical or horizontal) within the image.

Comment: yeah i want to separate that image into rows and columns,corresponding to each candidates no name and image...

Comment: after that i want create a separate image for each candidate with their corresponding no ,name , image  with size of 192*96..please help

Answer (score 1):

you may customize this to meet your requirement
http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that none of the programming techniques are capable of analyzing the semantics of an image, and thats why semantic analysis still an active problem in the area of Artificial intelligence.As per your requirements, you may be able to write a program for a particular image, but you cannot rely upon that program for a random image.(Just keep in mind,this might be helpful)

Now in case you actualy know the dimensions of image, and where to split, you can rely upon this [How to Split an Image into Chunks - Java ImageIO](http://kalanir.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-split-image-into-chunks-java.html) as @Anish mentioned,to get an idea about how to do,(note that this is not what you exactly want to do).

Comment: in ballot paper 1 name1 image1 in each row i want split this three parameters into separate images,how can i do this

Comment: see the link provided, you can get the idea about how to do, code it yourself, and post the code in case youre not successful,we'll try to help.

regards,